# Get events from graphite through api with use couple tags

Tags: graphite

How I can get events from graphite API use two tags or more?
For one tag I use this  **curl -s "http://graphite/events/get_data?tags=deploy&from=-3hours&until=now" | json_pp**
In the documentation for graphite I finde this "**The set parameter accepts an optional union or intersection argument to determine the behavior for filtering sets of tags (i.e. inclusive or exclusive). By default, Graphite uses a “lazy union” that will return any matching events for a given tag in a list of tags. This behavior is not intuitive and will therefore be deprecated in a future release.**"

Comment: Have you tried using an empty space between tags? I am using version 1.1.7 and this seems to work for me after quickly checking:
`http://graphite/events/get_data?from=-1hours&tags=deploy failed` (you can also use encoded space char `%20` instead)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on Graphite 1.1.7 by adding an encoded space char (`%20`) between the tags and in order to make the intersection work as expected I added a parameter `set=intersection`. Here is the query to pull the events for December 2020 using two tags with intersection:

```
http://graphite/events/get_data?from=00:00_20201201&until=00:00_20210101&tags=deploy%20failed&set=intersection
```